# Parsing comments with PetitParser in Pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, petitparser

Is there a simpler way to parse 1-line comments than this?

```
comment
    ^ '//' asParser ,
      (#any asParser starLazy: (#newline asParser)) ,
      #newline asParser
                  ==> [ :result | nil "Ignore comments" ]
program
    ^ (comment / instruction) star
        ==> [ :result | N2TProgramNode new
                                setNodes: (result copyWithout: nil) ]
```

I'm particularly unsure about the repetition of (#newline asParser) and the #copyWithout:.

**After Lukas' answer I came up with the much simpler following solution:**

```
program
    ^ programEntity star
        ==> [ :result | N2TProgramNode new setNodes: result]

programEntity
    ^ instruction trim: ignorable

ignorable
    ^ comment / #space asParser

comment
    ^ '//' asParser ,  #newline asParser negate star
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why wouldn't the following comment parser work as well?

```
'//' asParser , #newline asParser negate star
```

Also you might want to include the parsing of comments into the whitespace parsing with `trim:` (if the grammar allows it), so you don't have to think about it all the time.